# Coffee Script comprehension

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm new with coffee script so I'm wondering if I'm doing this right. I have an original implementation of `forEach` in JavaScript as follow:

```
if(!Array.prototype.forEach){
   Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, context){
     for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++){
        callback.call(context || null, this[i], i, this);
     }
   };
}
```

Here is how I currently write it in coffee script

```
if not Array.prototype.forEach
    Array.prototype.forEach = (callback, context) ->
    context ?= null 
    callback context, @[i], i, @ for i in @
```

But I wonder if it's correct, especially the context null checking seems redundant and whether the context is correctly applied as if I'm still using `call`. I tried to look up some examples regarding `apply` and `call` in coffee script but haven't got so much luck so far.

Comment: Well, obviously [it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%20not%20Array.prototype.forEach%0A%20%20Array.prototype.forEach%20%3D%20(callback%2C%20context)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20context%20%3F%3D%20null%20%0A%20%20%20%20callback%20context%2C%20%40%5Bi%5D%2C%20i%2C%20%40%20for%20i%20in%20%40) is not using `call`. And it works like `map` since it returns a `results` array.

Comment: There is a shortcut in `coffee-script` for prototypes. So, it's best to write `Array::forEach` instead of `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the context null checking seems redundant

Well, it also sets `context` to `null` if it was `undefined`. However, it [should](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18) become `undefined` actually.

> whether the context is correctly applied as if I'm still using call

No, since you're not using it.

[Better](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aif%20not%20Array.prototype.forEach%0A%20%20Array.prototype.forEach%20%3D%20%28callback%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20context%20%3D%20arguments%5B1%5D%20if%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%0A%20%20%20%20for%20el%2C%20i%20in%20%40%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20callback.call%20context%2C%20el%2C%20i%2C%20%40%20if%20i%20of%20%40%0A%20%20%20%20undefined):

```
if not Array.prototype.forEach
    Array.prototype.forEach = (callback) ->
        context = arguments[1] if arguments.length > 1
        for el, i in @
            callback.call context, el, i, @ if i of @
        undefined
```

Comment: +1, but I think it would be clearer/cleaner using a default argument rather than bringing the arguments object into it.  See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, the default argument is more coffeescript-like. The difference is the function's arity (`.length`), which should be `1` according to the spec. Of course, that's a minor issue :-)

Comment: This code is broken because `i` is not an index here. To fix it use `for i of @` loop and `if @[i] in @` check. Anyway, `for val, i in` loop seems better suited for this case.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny: Thanks for the hint, fixed now. You definitely know coffeescript better than me (wish I could upvote your answer twice) :-)

Answer (score 2):

`in` operator works completely different in `coffee-script`. So, in `coffee-script` your code will look like:

```
Array::forEach ?= (callback, context) ->
  callback.call context, elem, i, @ for elem, i in @
  return
```

Let's look at this code.

`Array::forEach` is just a shortcut for `Array.prototype.forEach`.

`?=` means "assign if not assigned".

`for elem, i in smth` is a special form of `coffee-script` `in` operator which allows you to capture an index of the element as well as it's value. Normally, `for .. in ..` operator in `coffee-script` operates only with elements **values** and not with its indexes.

`return` at the end of a function tells the compiler that you don't want to return the result of a last operation, which in your case is a `for` loop. Without it `coffee-script` will catch the result of each call inside `for` loop and then return them all as an single array. Obviously, you don't want this extra work to be done.

You can set a default value of the `context` variable to `null` , but this is not necessary since `undefined` works exactly the same as `null`. Your current code handles `context = false` the same way in handles undefined context. To force this behavior add `context ||= null` to the beginning of the function, but it seems redundant.

You can also use [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) to translate your `java-script` to `coffee-script`.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Bergi's answer for the explanation, but here's a slightly cleaner version of it since coffeescript parameters can have defaults.

```
if not Array.prototype.forEach
    Array.prototype.forEach = (callback,context = null) ->
        for i in @
            callback.call context, @[i], i, @ if i of @
        undefined
```

Comment: The default [should be `undefined` actually](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18), and can be omitted completely then :-)